# Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: django

O erro aponta para essa linha do código:

```
salt=hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
```

Antes funcionava normalmente, mas depois que passei para django 1.10.3 e python 3.5 aponta esse erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro também se dá pela diferença em que o Python 2 e 3 lidam diferentemente com strings.

Python 2

```
>>> type(str(random.random()).encode('utf-8'))
<type 'str'>
>>> type(str(random.random()))
<type 'str'>
```

Python 3:

```
>>> type(str(random.random()))
<type 'str'>

>>> type(str(random.random()).encode('utf-8'))
<class 'bytes'>
```

Então para funcionar, você vai ter que usar o método `.encode('utf-8')`, ficando assim:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> import random
>>> hashlib.sha1(str(random.random()).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[:5]
'7e8ff'
```

Comment: agora esta apontando o mesmo erro mas para a linha abaixo: activation_key=hashlib.sha1(salt+user.email).hexdigest()

Comment: Mesmo motivo que o anterior. Você tem que usar o método `.encode`.

`activation_key=hashlib.sha1(str(salt+user.email).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()`